# How to get rowindex when click from lookupedit or dateedit

Tags: c#

I want to get the index of the row when I click an item in lookupedit or datedit. But I keep getting errors like -27343243.

```
private void repositoryItemDateEdit2_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    DateEdit dateEdit = (DateEdit)sender;
    string dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateEdit.EditValue).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    int focusedRow = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(focusedRow, "colDate", dt);
}
```

Comment: if i remember correctly you can access the actual row through that `EventArgs`, try fiddle around in debug mode. alternatively, you can try accessing the parent of `DateEdit`.